# identifying valid url in python column pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe which has URL column

The valid URL should contain http://www.validurl.com. All other should be invalid URL 
I need to add another column which shows that URL is invalid

```
ID   URL 
1    http://www.validurl.com/sports
2    http://www.validurl.com
3    Nan
4    http://www.invalidurl.com
```

output should be

```
ID   URL                        Error message
1    http://www.validurl.com/sports
2    http://www.validurl.com
3    Nan                           Invalid
4    http://www.invalidurl.com     Invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use np.where to do the following

```
df['Error Message'] = np.where(df['URL'] == 'http://www.validurl.com', ' ', 'Invalid')
print df
```

which results in

```
  ID                        URL    Error Message
0   1    http://www.validurl.com         
1   2    http://www.validurl.com         
2   3                        Nan  Invalid
3   4  http://www.invalidurl.com  Invalid
```

Comment: Thanks its working fine. Just one quick question , how should i do it in case there is a URL value - 'http://www.validurl.com/sports' . & i want to mark it as a valid.  In other words, all urls that contain 'http://www.validurl.com' should be marked as valid

Comment: No problem. If u like the answer please upvote/accept the answer. Thanks.